# How to set resources folder in Intellij ide - java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have an issue that I am trying to solve a while.
I have a project that I imported using intelilj ide.
I want to use a file that exists in my resources folder.
The problem is that Intellij set the resource folder in wrong place.
This is the command in java

```
 ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String path = classLoader.getResource("fw8TAX12.pdf").getPath();
```

this is what Intelij returns:

```
X:\project\out\test\resources
```

however the file in in

```
   X:\project\src\test\resources
```

I do not understand what is the out folder in my project since I did not create it,
I need that getResource method return the accurate place of the resource.

I navigate to modules in intelij and under Resources and test resources tab, select the correct path, and nothing intelij just goes to the out folder and not to the src folder.
how can I make intelij understand what is the correct resources path

[image]

[image]

another try to set the resource folder that not worked
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In project frame, right click directory -> mark as -> Resources.  Or click the Resources button in the header in your first screen shot (with that directory selected as shown).

Comment: I tried the second scenario, and nothing intellij just refuse to set resource folder, he just geos to to out/resource/ I will add pic in the first comment above,how to do the first scenario?

Comment: I also navigate to the wrong resource folder that is under the out folder, and mark it as exclude, it was red. I run again my code   ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        String path = classLoader.getResource("fw8TAX12.pdf").getPath();     and still get resource from the out folder. I do not know how to teach intelij the correct path